# Limits of functions and L'Hopital rule

Tags: calculus, limits

Suppose we have two differentiable positive functions $f,g$ with both $f(n), g(n) \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$, and such that $f(n) < 1 < g(n)$ for each $n$. What is 
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{f'(n)}{(fg)'(n)}?
$$
When does it converge? When does it diverge? Thank you.

Comment: The limit need not be of an indeterminate form (i.e. we cannot conclude $f'(n)\to 0$, for example)

Comment: Thanks. Could you please give an example of such a "non-indeterminate" function $f$ with $f(n) \to 1$ but $f'(n) \not\to 0$? Note that I added the requirement that $f(n) < 1 < g(n)$ for all $n$. 

I have tried easy examples of the form, say $f(n) = 1 - 1/polynomial(n)$ and $g(n) = 1 + 1/polynomial(n)$ (and so both $f'(n),g'(n) \to 0$) and it seems that the limit is always $\leq 1$. But I wonder if one could prove this in the general case (at least for "indeterminate" forms)? Thanks a lot.